# Using multiple libraries with one canvas in Adobe Animate

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, createjs

I'm developping a game with several screens and a lot of assets (png, jpg..), and I would like to separate the assets in multiple FLA files so that I can export more quickly instead of exporting all in one time.
I've succedded in doing that with adding the javascript files of the libraries in my html page and it works great with vector files (because they are in the JS file). But with spritesheets and single image files, it doesn't work, in fact they are not loaded.

How can I add the libraries to the loader (createjs.loadQueue) ?

In my HTML script there are these lines :

```
var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
loader.addEventListener("fileload", function(evt){handleFileLoad(evt,comp)});
loader.addEventListener("complete", function(evt){handleComplete(evt,comp)});
loader.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){handleProgress(evt,comp)});
loader.loadManifest(lib.properties.manifest);
```

But it only loads the "comp" library. I have also comp2, comp3...

thanks !